# Set JSONArray into String in POJO class using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson, json-deserialization

I have a jsonarray and for that i have created pojo class. Now, i want to set jsonarray into a string. When i am doing that it throws error of `The JsonDeserializer StringTypeAdapter failed to deserialize json object given the type class java.lang.String` . And this question is differ because i want to set that jsonarray into String So, any one have any idea ?

Comment: Could you incluse some of your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586229/problem-deserializing-bugzilla-json-using-googles-gson

Comment: But, i want to set that jsonarray into a string variable. So, can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

[Gson.toJson()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(com.google.gson.JsonElement)) returns a String..

So like..

`String myArrayAsAString = gsonInstance.toJson(myJsonArray);`

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Where i put this code? I mean i called this when my json came, `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
                ProductInfo item = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), POJO_Class.class);`  and my POJO_Class have getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 1):

u can set the method uself.
    public class BookDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer {

```
@Override
public Book deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
  throws JsonParseException {
final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

final JsonElement jsonTitle = jsonObject.get("title");
final String title = jsonTitle.getAsString();

final String isbn10 = jsonObject.get("isbn-10").getAsString();
final String isbn13 = jsonObject.get("isbn-13").getAsString();

final JsonArray jsonAuthorsArray = jsonObject.get("authors").getAsJsonArray();
final String[] authors = new String[jsonAuthorsArray.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {
  final JsonElement jsonAuthor = jsonAuthorsArray.get(i);
  authors[i] = jsonAuthor.getAsString();
}

final Book book = new Book();
book.setTitle(title);
book.setIsbn10(isbn10);
book.setIsbn13(isbn13);
book.setAuthors(authors);
return book;
}
}
```

http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

Comment: But for this i have to make separate classes, because my response is too long, and it have more than 4 array. So, for all i have to make classes ?

Comment: maybe u should provide the json  ,the POJO class and the place u want to set that jsonarray into String

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an array of productInfo:

```
List<ProductInfo> productInfos = new ArrayList<>();
// fill your productInfos, etc.
```

Then you want to get String representation of productInfos' JsonArray:

```
JsonArray productInfoJsonArray = (JsonArray) new Gson().toJsonTree(productInfos,
            new TypeToken<List<ProductInfo>>() {
            }.getType());

productInfoJsonArray.getAsString();
```

I'm not entirely sure about what you're trying to achieve, but I hope that above snippet helps.